# Application of Stoke's Theorem: Wrong parametrization?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> 1. Show that the path $\mathbf{x}(t)=( \cos t, \sin t, \sin 2t )$ lies on the surface $z=2xy$.
> 2. Evaluate $$\oint_C (y^3+ \cos x)\, dx+(\sin y+z^2)\, dy+x\,dz$$ where $C$ is the closed curve parametrized and oriented by the path
>      $\mathbf{x}$ in 1.

Question $1$ is trivial. It is pure substitution and double-angle formula.

I am stuck with question $2$. I think it should be an application of the Stoke's Theorem: $$ \iint_S \nabla \times \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\oint_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}$$ where $S$ is the surface bounded and $C$ is the corresponding boundary. Now, $$\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=(2z, -1, -3y^2)$$ and then I parametrize the bounded area: $\mathbf{X}(s,t)=(s \cos t, s \sin t, 2s^2 \sin t \cos t)$ where $0 \leq s \leq 1, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. But it leads me to a messy looking vector surface integral. I suppose it is a wrong way to tackle this question.

I also try to solve this vector surface integral without parametrizing the surface. I then find $$ \iint_S \frac{-8xy^2 + 2x -3y^2}{\sqrt{4y^2+4x^2+1}}\,dS.$$ Again, messy!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you simply compute the line integral, instead of using Stokes' theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the line integral directly. Upon substitution you will get

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (\sin^3(t)+\cos(\cos(t)))(-\sin(t)) + (\sin(\sin(t)) + \sin^2(2t))\cos(t) + \cos(t) \, dt.$$

The only integral that is not zero is

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (- \sin^4(t)) \, dt,$$

whose value is $\displaystyle - \frac{3 \pi}{4}.$

Comment: Thanks for replying (again!) Is there any simple argument to show that other integrals are zero? Or do I need to compute them explicitly?

Comment: We know that $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos(t) \, dt = 0.$$ Write $$\sin^2(2t) = \frac{1-\cos(4t)}{2}.$$ This multiplied by $\cos(t)$ will also yield zero, because $$\cos(4t) \cos(t) = \frac{1}{2} (\cos(5t) + \cos(3t)).$$ The integrals $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\sin(t)) \cos(t) \, dt, \quad \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(\cos(t))(-\sin(t)) \, dt$$ I had an intuition they'd be zero through the substitutions $u = \sin(t)$ and $v = \cos(t)$. I used Mathematica to confirm. To really prove they're zero you'd have to compute them in each interval where the substitutions are valid (meaning the derivatives are always nonzero).